# Polymorphism - Using an object that inherits from an interface rather than the interface directly

Tags: c#, interface, polymorphism

In a C# class, is it possible to use a `List<T>`, where `T` is a class that implements an `interface`, but the `List<T>` is of a class that inherits from the `interface`, and not from the `interface` directly?

Here is some code to explain:

```
public interface ITestClass
{
    List<IListItem> list { get; set; }
}

public interface IListItem
{
    //some data
}

public class ListItem : IListItem
{
    //some data
}
```

The following code compiles correctly:

```
public class TestClass : ITestClass
{
    public List<IListItem> list { get; set; }
}
```

However, the following code does not compile correctly:

```
public class TestClass : ITestClass
{
    public List<ListItem> list { get; set; }
}
```

Can someone please explain why, and how I should modify my above code?

The context of the situation is as follows:

I am wanting to `serialize` a `TestClass` object to file, however, it cannot be serialized with a `List<T>` where `T` is an `interface`. I still want the `ITestClass` to specify that the `list` needs to `inherit` from `IListItem` if possible.

Here is the serializtion code that I am using:

```
IFormatter formatter = new BinaryFormatter();
```

Thanks

Comment: Which serializer are you using?

Comment: serializers often have problems with interfaces, because they need to know the class that they have to create on deserialization. If they only have an interface, what should they create?

Comment: Perfect example of [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377). Do you want to fix compilation error or do you want to fix your serialization problem?

Comment: @Sinatr, I think in this case it's clear that he wants to fix his serialization problem.

Comment: How about making the `ITestClass` interface take a generic type parameter and type constraint?

Comment: @DavidG: Can you please give me a code example of how to do this? I am not sure what you are referring to.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could make your interface take a generic type parameter and constrain it to types of `IListItem`:

```
public interface ITestClass<T> where T : IListItem
{
    List<T> list { get; set; }
}
```

And now your `TestClass` becomes:

```
public class TestClass : ITestClass<ListItem>
{
    public List<ListItem> list { get; set; }
}
```

As we don't know which serialiser you are using, here's an example with XML:

```
//Set up the object to serialise
var testObject = new TestClass();
testObject.list = new List<ListItem>();
testObject.list.Add(new ListItem());

var serializer = new System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer(typeof(TestClass));
StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
XmlWriter writer = XmlWriter.Create(sw);
serializer.Serialize(writer, testObject);
var xml = sww.ToString();
```

And another example now you told us you are using the `BinaryFormatter` to serialise:

```
var formatter = new BinaryFormatter();
var stream = new MemoryStream();

//Serialise the object to memory
formatter.Serialize(stream, testObject);

//Reset the position back to start of stream!
stream.Position = 0;

//Deserialise back into a new object
var newTestObject = (TestClass)formatter.Deserialize(stream);
```